# How can I view certificate details on a smart card

Tags: rhel, openssl, certificates, smartcard

I am using `p11tool` on CentOS to read a PIV smart card.  The card is being read via the `coolkey` package driver (using `libcoolkeypk11.so`, per `p11-kit list-modules`)

I can get a listing of the certs on there using

```
p11tool --list-all-certs 'pkcs11:model=;manufacturer=;serial=;token=CoolKey'
```

The list of certs only includes the URL, Type, Label, and ID.  Using the GUI Smart Card Manager from the RedHat Enterprise Security Client (`esc` package, which requires `coolkey` (**not** `opensc`)), I can drill down to view certificate details, like the cert's serial number and fingerprints.

I tried `p11tool --info <certurl>` hoping that would provide the details, but that still only lists the four fields seen with `--list-all-certs`.

UPDATE: I also tried `openssl x509 -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -text -in <certurl>` but that failed, with the message

```
140067620280208:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:402:fopen('<certurl>','r')
```

How can I view those details using p11tool and/or other command line tools?

Comment: The `openssl` tool expects a file as parameter after the `-in` switch. You should export the certificate from the smart card into a file.

Comment: You need to have `opensc` installed, which gives you `pkcs15-tool` amongst others.  Use it with the `--list-certificates` and `--list-certificate <id>` options.

Comment: @garerthTheRed.  Thanks - Centos is still using `coolkey`, not `opensc`.  I'll need to look at whether installing `opensc` will create any conflicts or problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `--export` flag was the key (Thanks for the tip, @Johan Myréen).  Thus, to see the cert's details and fingerprints, this works:

`p11tool --export <certurl> | openssl x509 -text -noout`

`p11tool --export <certurl> | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout` #defaults to SHA1 fingerprint

`p11tool --export <certurl> | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -md5` #for MD5 fingerprint